# SharePoint API with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, sharepoint, soap

I am using an API from github for integration with SharePoint via PHP.

http://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API

This is working well apart from one list. The list in question has a lot of files in it, one of which uses special character &#18

Reading some resources on the web it would appear that .NET webservices do not check for these characters - verbatim from another source

> For backward compatibility reasons .NET webservices do not support XML 1.1 which would allow these character as explained in the following article:
>
> The web service stub (server) routines implemented in .NET framework do not bother about the invalid characters when encoding the XML response. They encode the invalid characters as numeric character reference like  for the vertical tab char. The problem occurs in the web service proxy (client) routines. These raise an exception when an entity is returned which is not allowed in XML 1.0:

The PHP Sharepoint API uses the PHP soap client to call the SharePoint API to retrieve the information. However if it finds an error such as the character &#18 in the reponse it simply disregards it and throws an exceptiopn.

Hacking the API code a little I have retrieved the XML it is returning with __getLastResponse() and can see the character in the string:

```
wic_YResolution:DW|72.0000000000000&#13;&#10;_Comments:SW|&#18;Ã¸&#15;;&#13;&#10;wic_System_ApplicationName
```

Obviously I could add a special case and return this XML rather than the nice Soap Object and parse this differently, but what I would like to know is if there is a way to tell the Soap client to parse the response anyway, ignore invalid characters and give me a nice response back as it does with everything else.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.